# In c++ stl map, delete entries with duplicate values

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

Consider map mymap has entries

```
<'a', 111>  
<'b', 567>  
<'c', 956>  
<'d', 222>  
<'e', 111>  
<'f', 222>  
<'h', 222>  
<'i', 492>
```

and so on...
How to delete entries in map where values are duplicated.
e.g. value 111 is present for keys 'a' and 'e'. So keep map entry for 'a' and delete entry for 'e'
For value 222 keep entry 'd' and delete entries 'f' and 'h'.
I am looking for solution with best possible space and time complexity

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service. Please show your efforts

Comment: Construct a set of the values and if the value is already in the set, remove the entry from your map. ~10-12 lines of code.

Comment: "So keep map entry for 'a' and delete entry for 'e'" -- Why? Why not keep the map entry for 'e' and delete the one for 'a'? The rules you want also need to be part of your question.

Comment: @hvd I suppose he wants to keep the entry with the lowest key, but you're right this should be specified in the question

Comment: @MichaelWalz "Lowest" is also underspecified so would need to be explained in the question :) In ASCII, so in most C++ implementations, `'B' < 'a'`, but this may or may not be desirable for the OP.

Comment: @hvd "lowest" under the maps `key_compare` member, most likely

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short-order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far as a [mcve], the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. It may help to re-read [ask].

Comment: My apologies. As indicated by seniors, I should have added more details and put my  coding efforts. I was looking for space optimised solution where even an additional set is not needed. But looks like set is must. I will take necessary care while posting further questions.  Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an interesting problem, if a little off topic.

because the value of your map is hashable and equality comparable, then we can do this in linear time, using an `unordered_set` to determine whether the value has been seen before:

This code is c++17:

```
void comb(std::map<char, int>& themap)
{
    std::unordered_set<int> seen;
    seen.reserve(themap.size());

    // iterate through the map in key order...
    auto current = begin(themap);
    const auto last = end(themap);
    while(current != last)
    {
        auto&&[key, value] = *current;

        // try to insert the value into the 'seen' set.
        if (seen.insert(value).second)
            // if we succeeded, then we're the first ocurrence of the
            // value so move to next node
            ++current;
        else
            // otherwise, erase this node and move to the next
            // (idiomatic method)
            current = themap.erase(current);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>

int main() {
  std::map<char, int> mymap
  {
    {'a', 111}, {'b', 567}, {'c', 956}, {'d', 222}, 
    {'e', 111}, {'f', 222}, {'h', 222}, {'i', 492},
  };

  std::set<int> existingvalues;

  for (auto it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); it++)
  {
    if (existingvalues.find(it->second) != existingvalues.end())
      mymap.erase(it--);                  // value already encountered => remove entry
    else
      existingvalues.insert(it->second);  // value not yet encountered => remeber it
  }

  for (auto it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); it++)
    std::cout << "<'" << it->first << "', " << it->second << ">\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another possible solution that involves iterating through the map container 2 times, second time will have less element to iterate through if there were duplicate values:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>

template <typename T, typename U>
void RemoveDuplicateValues(std::map<T, U> &m)
{
    std::map<U, T> tmp;
    std::for_each(m.rbegin(), m.rend(), [&tmp](auto const &p)
    {
        tmp[p.second] = p.first;
    });

    m.clear();
    for (auto const &p : tmp)
        m[p.second] = p.first;
}

int main()
{
    std::map<char, int> m
    {
        { 'a', 111 },{ 'b', 567 },{ 'c', 956 },{ 'd', 222 },
        { 'e', 111 },{ 'f', 222 },{ 'h', 222 },{ 'i', 492 }
    };

    RemoveDuplicateValues(m);

    // test
    for (auto const &p : m)
        std::cout << p.first << " " << p.second << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/oThy17

```
a 111
b 567
c 956
d 222
i 492
```